# What does exactly does GNU make dep do?

Tags: make, c, gnu, gnu-make, autotools

I am trying to understand GNU Make and trying to understand some c code and GNU autotools.

There's a folder let's say lib, with three subfolders and a makefile.

```
lib
...libA
...---compile.sh
...---file.h
...---file.c
...libB
...---file1.h
...---file2.h
...---file3.h
...---file.c
...---Makefile
...libC
...---file1.h
...---file1.c
...---file2.c
...---file3.c
...---file4.c
...Makefile
```

So after looking at this folder structure and the `make dep` command
The program goes into the folder, runs `make dep` then finishes.

The above `make dep` command gets called after a configure script is run to detect and setup the env.

What exactly is `make dep` doing?

Comment: I would presume only the holder of the `Makefile` will ever know. `cat Makefile | grep "dep"` (makes and build the dependencies)

Comment: ... seriously though, open and read the `Makefile` and you will know. It is an arbitrary target delineated in the `Makefile` and without showing the file, **we** will never know.

Comment: How's that an answer, why would you think that I didn't look in the Makefiles? There's no deps: that's why I am asking the question...

Comment: It's not an answer... it's a comment. And it is `dep` not `deps`. And no, it wouldn't surprise me if you didn't look.

Comment: [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dep` would be defined in the makefile. Makefiles are a simple way to automate things (such as compiling binaries and installing them). `make` is basically a scripting language.

The makefile will contain a section like this:

```
dep:
    some command
    maybe an if statement or two
    some other command
```

That section will define what `make dep` does. Judging by the name, it probably has something to do with dependencies. The makefile will also contain other sections (such as `all`, `default`, `install`, etc) to take care of compile-time configuration, compiling, and installation.

Most packages have install documentation available somewhere to explain the options in the makefile. Reading that and looking at the corresponding sections in the makefile is a good way to learn about how `make` works.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I looked through all the makefiles and the `dep:` sections are all empty. Most likely for some features that haven't been implemented yet. Thanks anyways.

Comment: If I only would have made my comment an answer, I would have been respected ... good to know @user1610950. God speed my friend.

Comment: Oh, and thanks for this tidbit: `dep:` *sections are all empty*